# Comparar un campo de SQLite en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

estoy tratando de comparar un campo llamado NOMBRE de tipo TEXT con una variable que tengo en otra actividad, como podria sacar ese campo que contiene el nombre de un usuario y poder compararlo?
[image: Sqlite]

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo parecido a esto.

```
public Cursor consultar(String busqueda) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(busqueda != null) {
            cursor = db.query(TABLE_PROVEEDORES, new String[]{ID, NOMBRE, FECHA}, NOMBRE + " LIKE?", new String[]{busqueda+"%"}, null, null, null);
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

esto te retornara un curso en este caso utilice la clausula `LIKE`, ya solo llamas a este metodo y te retornada un cursor, ya con eso accedes a la información que necesites.